# Incompatible Units Problem

Tags: units, physical-constants

I am trying to use quantities with physical units to calculate my result, but I encountered the "Incompatible units" problem. I don't know what is going on. Here is my code, could I have some second-opinions?

```
Convert[λ^2 Ins/(π ω ℏ) /. ω -> (
     2 π c)/λ /. ℏ -> h/(2 π) /. {Ins -> 
    51*10^-3 Watt/Centimeter^2, c -> SpeedOfLight, 
   h -> PlanckConstant, λ -> 369*10^-9 Meter}, Hertz]
```

Comment: Does your code work if you define your variables as `Quantity`s? I.e. `\[Lambda] = Quantity[396*^-9,"Meter"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UnitConvert[λ^2 Ins/(π ω ℏ) /. ω -> \
(2 π c)/λ /. ℏ -> h/(2 π) /. {Ins -> 
     Quantity[51*10^-3, "Watts"/("Centimeters")^2], 
    c -> Entity["PhysicalConstant", "SpeedOfLight"]["Value"], 
    h -> Entity["PhysicalConstant", "PlanckConstant"][
      "Value"], λ -> Quantity[369*10^-9, "Meters"]}, 
  "Hertz"] // N
```

> Quantity[4.10604[Times]10^7, "Hertz"]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code, I decided to test the comment I sent you. Try the following:

```
\[Lambda] = Quantity[369*^-9,"Meters"]
h = Quantity[1, "PlanckConstant"]
c = Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"]
Ins = Quantity[51*^-3, "Watts"/"Centimeters"^2]
hBar = h/(2*\[Pi])
Omega = (2 * \[Pi] c)/\[Lambda]

N[UnitConvert[\[Lambda]^2 * Ins/(\[Pi] * Omega * hBar),"Hertz"]]
```

As far as I'm aware, there's not an easier way to work with units other than the `Quantity` function.